# C++ functor and list template

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I've implemented a list and iterator templates, the find method is supposed to receive a functor so I declared and implemented one but I keep getting the error that there's no such an object!
"**no matching function for call to object of type const findBond** "

here's the implementation of the find method:

```
template <class T>
template <class Predicate>
Iterator<T> List<T> :: find(const Predicate &predicate) {
    for (Iterator<T> iterator=begin(); iterator != end(); ++iterator) {

        if (predicate(*iterator)) {

            return iterator;

        }

    }

    return end();

}

// predicate is a functor that is supposed to return a boolean value
```

here's the function object:

```
class findBond{

    Bond& bond;

public:

    findBond( Bond& bond1) : bond(bond1) {}

    bool operator() (Bond& bond1){

            return bond==bond1;

            }
};
```

I'm trying to use them here:

```
void InvestmentBroker :: addBond(const string& name, double value, int amount ){
    Bond bond = *new Bond(name, value, amount);

    if (bondsDatabase.find(findBond(bond)) != bondsDatabase.end()) {

        //throw an exception

    } else { 

       // insert bond to dataBase

    }
}
```

I included the needed files so it's not about the includes

What's wrong? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your find method takes a `const Predicate&` as its argument. That means you can only call `const` methods of the predicate. However, your functor's call operator is not declared `const`. You can fix your problem by declaring it `const` like this:

```
bool operator() (Bond& bond1) const {/* do stuff */ }
```

That `const` at the end of the declaration means that you can't modify `this` from within the function, which in turn means you can call the function on a `const` object.

Comment: That's right, how did I miss that? It works,
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a constness issue to me - `findBond` should be `const` on most arguments.

Change  `findBond` to this

```
class findBond{
    const  Bond& bond;

public:

    findBond( const Bond& bond1) : bond(bond1) {}

    bool operator() const ( const Bond& bond1){
         return bond==bond1;
    }
};
```